# How Can I remove Required Attribute Of Gravity Form Field With Jquery?

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am aware of gravity Form Plugin but don't know how can i remove required attribute of gravity form's text field with jquery.I want to make that text field mandatory if i check some specific checkbox and want to remove required attribute from that text field if i check other checkboxes.Is It Possible?Please Provide me some solution/referal links that may become helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this css

```
span.gfield_required.gfield_required_text {font-size: 0;}
span.gfield_required.gfield_required_text::before {content: "*";color: #fff;font-size: 20px;}
```